# How can I send a html file and the results of my database request to my page (Express)?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a big problem, I wrote a almost complete webpage in Express with jade. But now my lecturer told me that jade isn't allowed to use. We need to do everything with php, node or/and html code but I don't get how I can send my database entries to my webpage without an engine.

Here is an example

```
function userPage(req, res, id) {
var url = req.url;
if(url.indexOf("id=")> -1){     
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM photageDB.users WHERE ID=?; SELECT * FROM photageDB.users INNER JOIN photageDB.movie ON (photageDB.movie.userID = photageDB.users.ID) WHERE photagedb.users.ID=?;', [id, id], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err)  { throw err; }    
        var data = rows[0];
        var movies = rows[1];
        if (req.cookies.userID == id || req.cookies.isAdmin == 1) {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../views" , "/profile.html"));
            //res.render("profile", {data : JSON.stringify(rows[0]), movies : JSON.stringify(rows[1])});
        } else {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../views" , "/user.html"));
            //res.render("user", {data : JSON.stringify(rows[0]), movies : JSON.stringify(rows[1])});
        }
    });
}
```

I used render and passed the values but now? How can I access them?

Bests

Martin

Comment: A template engine, at its most basic level, just replaces placeholders in text with data from somewhere else. If you aren't allowed to use a preexisting one, then you have to write your own.

Comment: He probably doesn't fully understand what Jade is or what a template engine is. You could try something like Nunjucks, which looks a lot like HTML and is similar to PHP (but even in PHP you'd use a good template engine).

Comment: what'a bs. it's only cuz your lecturer don't understand jade. php is kind of a template engine, so why shouldn't you get to use one with express?! I'm sure that if you used [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) or [ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs) it would probably be more acceptable since it uses html as the default language. all dynamic codes get written within some special tags

Comment: doT.js like many other can allow you to precompile a template into a compressed function into a new file - use that and see what you lecturer think about that :P

Comment: I looked at the whitelist and those are allowed JQuery, Bootstrap, php5-json, jVectorMap, express, express-session, nodejs-mysql,bcrypt-nodejs,
 JavaScript SHA-512, 
 Bootstrap datetimepicker,
 MaterializeCSS,  CanvasJSâ€‹, 
 Node.js sendmail,
 Node.js pg,
 Node.js body-parser, 
 connect-favicons,
 morgan,
 node-schedule,
 nodemailer,
 TinyMCE,
 Online Molmassen Rechner,
 W3-CSS Framework,
 Chart JS,
 Foundation,Goutte

Answer (score 1):

You need some type of view engine if you want to have dynamic stuff (e.g. database entries) in your `profile.html` and `user.html` files. Of course you could also just compile one giant string of html in JS and send that to the client like so:

`res.send('<html><head>...</head><body>' + user.name + '</body></html');`

But that would make absolutely zero sense.

Because you’re allowed to use Node—and by extension Express—you should also be allowed to use Jade (which has been renamed to [Pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)), since this is just a view engine for Express and it is also written in NodeJS.

So my guess is either your teacher either doesn’t understand what Jade does, or they want you to to use plain NodeJS without anything like Express on top.